# Can fragment extend an abstract class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The abstract class extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment so MyFragment can do something as a fragment. But MyFragment cannot be converted to Fragment when extending an abstract class. 
How can fragment extend an abstract class?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
        case (R.id.nav_bin):
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_content, new MyFragment()).commit();
            break;
         ...
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseActivity implements ...{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View baseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
        return baseView;
    }

}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Fragment implements ...{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`...BaseActivity extends Fragment...`

Firstly, please don't use this naming convention -- that's super confusing. Try `BaseFragment` instead. `BaseActivity` implies that it extends from the `Activity` class.

Secondly, your issue probably stems from mixed `android.app.Fragment` imports and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` imports. Make sure that your `BaseFragment` class is importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and not `android.app.Fragment`.